# Ruby On Rails --api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest

I create new Rails application with --api parameter, like on manual http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html

```
rails new app2 --api
```

For scaffold I use

```
bin/rails generate scaffold People first_name:string last_name:string age:integer
```

And Rails generate controller with not only actions for json result, and don't need "new" and "edit" actions, and html rendering
Also it generates

```
  create      app/views/people
  create      app/views/people/index.html.erb
  create      app/views/people/edit.html.erb
  create      app/views/people/show.html.erb
  create      app/views/people/new.html.erb
  create      app/views/people/_form.html.erb
```

that I don't need, because I need only API
Why?
I want to receive result, like I use rails-api gem
Version of Rails is 4.2.5

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to generate `model` and `controller`, you can use:

```
bin/rails generate resource People first_name:string last_name:string age:integer
```

Comment: I need scaffold like in "rails-api" gem, with CRUD actions but only for REST API on json. Without html templates and html actions

Answer (score 1):

I found answer. "--api" command is only for 5.0 Rails